# Eclipse Task Tags

Tags: eclipse, tags, task, editor

I am having trouble using Task tags. The issue is that there are several pre-existing libraries included in the PHP project which are from other authors. I have a total of around 100 @todo and FIXME tags, however Eclipse refuses to let me delete (greyed out).

I have tried removing these tags from the Task Tag editor, restarting Eclipse etc but it will not forget them.

Deleting from the code is impractical - if I need to update or re-install libraries I'll have to remove them all each time.

Following Jonathan David Arndt helpful advise I've attached the screen shot showing TODO unchecked but Eclipse still shows them[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the Task tags in Eclipse, and third-party libraries with TODO and FIXME tags also bother me.

The solution depends in part on how your code environment and individual projects are setup. With Java, it's easy, since third-party code is separated into different projects. With PHP, third-party code *might* be in a separate project, but you might have it nested in your project for convenience.

In any case, on the Eclipse `Tasks` tab, in the upper-right corner, there is a little upside-down caret. Click on "Configure Contents..."

From there, you can filter out elements based on where they are located, what text they contain, and several other helpful criteria.

[image: Eclipse Tasks tab]

Comment: Perfect thanks, my edit to show the screen shots was caused by a single incorrect directory selection, still containing TODOs

Comment: I am having trouble creating tags now - I have added an ampersand tag (a)FIXME and also put in in the middle column Text Contains field. I have the put this in a comment (part of a function description eg /** funcdesc (a)FIXME this bit doesnt work */ but its not picking it up - how do I get it to force scan to check

Comment: The UI for this screen really is quite difficult (it is not obvious to me what the problem is in the new screenshot). Make sure the `Description` contains something. Try checking/unchecking all the items in the list of `Types`. And try changing the selected `Scope` -- Scope is quite dependent on what element is currently selected over in the File Explorer.

Comment: do you know if it scans straightaway

Comment: Yes, it ought to scan immediately after you click OK.

Comment: Issue was its only looking in php files and by chance I was testing in a random file opened for editing - I'll have to work out why its ignoring js